# How to print from the variable $test, that is gig1 port is trunk port using TCL regexp?

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL/TK. I want to check whether gig1 port is "trunk" or "access" from the following $test variable.

```
set test {
 interface gig1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 1
  no switchport trunk native tagged
 interface gig2
   switchport mode access
   switchport access vlan 2
   no switchport trunk native tagged
 }
```

How to print from the above variable $test, that is gig1 port is trunk port?

First I want filter "gig1" and whatever appears after that.

please suggest your ideas?

Thanks,

kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set test {
 interface gig1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 1
  no switchport trunk native tagged
 interface gig2
  switchport mode access
  switchport access vlan 2
  no switchport trunk native tagged
 }

 if {![regexp {interface gig1
  switchport mode ([a-zA-Z]*)} $test line var]} {
 puts "invalid parsing"
 }
 puts "Gig1 port is a $var port"
```

OUTPUT will be:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop>tclsh test.tcl
Gig1 port is a trunk port

C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop>
```

I hope it will be useful for you.

Thanks,

Balu P.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach {a b} [set f 0 ; lmap w $test {
    if {$f} {
        set f 0
        set w
    } else {
        set f [expr {$w in {interface mode}}]
        continue
    }
}] {
    puts "Port $a is a $b port"
}
```

prints

```
Port gig1 is a trunk port
Port gig2 is a access port
```

This works by a) mapping the original list to a reduced list that only contains the elements that immediately follow either of the words "interface" and "mode", and then b) iterating over that reduced list, taking two words each time and putting them in an output statement.

The `lmap` command traverses a list, typically using the current list item in a script that produces one result for every item in the original list. For example, the list `{a reduced list}` can be mapped to a list consisting of the string lengths of the items:

```
lmap item {a reduced list} {string length $item}
# => {1 7 4}
```

The resulting list doesn't have to have as many items as the original list. One can e.g. produce a list that only consists of words that have at least three characters:

```
lmap item {to a reduced list} {
    if {[string length $item] < 3} {
        continue
    } else {
        set item
    }
}
# => {reduced list}
```

The `continue` command, in this context, causes the `lmap` command to skip one item in the resulting list. The `break` command, similarly, truncates the resulting list at the point where it was called.

So, if you want to have a list consisting only of selected words from a list of words, this is the basic code skeleton (assuming the original list is in the variable `test`):

```
lmap w $test {
    if { ‹condition› } {
        set w
    } else {
        continue
    }
}
```

This invocation will traverse the original list and append the current word to the resulting list if and only if the condition is true. The condition we wanted was that the preceding word be either "interface" and "mode". But `lmap` only lets us look at one word at a time! (Actually not really true, see below.)

Imagine that we have a flag variable, `f` that somehow contains `true` if the preceding word was one of the looked-for words, and otherwise contains `false`.

```
lmap w $test {
    if {$f} {
        set w
    } else {
        continue
    }
}
```

Now, what do we know about the value of this flag variable? Well, it starts out as `false` (before any words are read, there is no preceding word), and every time we add a word to the resulting list, it becomes `false` (the words we add aren't in the looked-for list). Note that I'm using `0` for falsehood: it's a legal boolean value in Tcl.

```
set f 0
lmap w $test {
    if {$f} {
        set f 0
        set w
    } else {
        continue
    }
}
```

When do we look for the words "interface" and "mode"? Every time the flag indicates `false`. What happens when we find them? We set the flag to `true`, which means that the next word will be added to the resulting list.

```
set f 0
lmap w $test {
    if {$f} {
        set f 0
        set w
    } else {
        set f [expr {$w in {interface mode}}]
        continue
    }
}
```

I could have used an `if` command here to set `f` to `1`, but it's more convenient to set `f` to the result of the predicate `expr {$w in {interface mode}}`.

When we evaluate the above, we get the list `{gig1 trunk gig2 access}`. We can make that more readable by inserting the values into a string template:

```
puts "Port $a is a $b port"
```

To make that work, we can use the `foreach` command to pick out a pair of words during each iteration and printing the template.

```
foreach {a b} {gig1 trunk gig2 access} {
    puts "Port $a is a $b port"
}
```

We can put these two parts, getting a reduced word list and printing it, together by replacing the list literal in the `foreach` invocation by the code in the `set` + `lmap` script within brackets. What you get is the first code section in this answer.

I did say that it isn't quite true that `lmap` only lets you look at one item during each iteration. You can actually look at several items in the same list or other lists, which means that this works:

```
lmap w1 $test w2 [lrange $test 1 end] {
    if {$w1 in {interface mode}} {
        set w2
    } else {
        continue
    }
}
```

But that's almost cheating.

Documentation: [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [in operator](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Could you please explain how this script works. Thanks in advance.